# CodeIgniter - Form Validation on AJAX data(of multidimensional associative array) sent after stringification

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is a quick demo of javascript portion:

```
            var student = {};

            student['name'] = 'ABC';
            student['dob'] = '1-1-2015';
            student['address'] = {};
            student['address']['home'] = 'somewhere on earth';
            student['address']['office'] = 'near mars';
            student['contactnum'] = {};
            student['contactnum']['home'] = {};
            student['contactnum']['home']['mob'] = '12345';
            student['contactnum']['home']['phone'] = '987';
            student['contactnum']['office'] = {};
            student['contactnum']['office']['mob'] = '12345';
            student['contactnum']['office']['phone'] = '987';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/ajax/addStudent');?>",
                data: {'d': JSON.stringify( student ) },
                contentType: 'application/json'
            })
```

As you can see am sending this associative array object to the CodeIgniter page via AJAX. But the question is, how to use the [FormValidation helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) at the server side! To my belief, the validation helper only checks for single field names. Since all the validations needed for me is in that helper, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but want to know how to write validation config for this data at CodeIgniter page!

Comment: First of all I would like to notice, that you trying to get JSON string from empty array, but with self writen properties. 
JSON.stringify( student ) allways will return "[]".
Try to change _student_ to object insted of array.

Comment: you can use [http query builder](http://php.net//manual/es/function.http-build-query.php)                    for your post requset

Comment: In the Controller you will again have to get the values from the array u posted.
`$stuName = $this->input->post('student['name']');`
then apply the validations over those variables you got.

Comment: @user2466277: Thank you so much. I didn't noticed that. I just double checked and saw that it was giving empty after stringify! I just changed the `[]` in my code to `{}` and now it works. Now just have to figure out a the CI validation part

Comment: @miglio: Am not sure how that function will help in my case. Am sending the data from client side to the server side. If you were suggesting to decode the JSON at client side to a multidimensional associative array and then do the query build and submit it to the page again via code and then applying the validation rule, then I it's much a good way! If your idea is something else, then please let me know. Thank you

Comment: It has been found that the data is not receiving at server side. Because I tried to dump the return value of `$this->input->post()`. But is always giving empty!

Comment: Ok. Found that if we don't supply a key along with the stringified data, CI would return empty when fetching the contents from the `$this->input->post()`

Comment: try this:

 data: {name:'d', value: JSON.stringify( student ) }

or

 data: $.param([{name:'d', value: JSON.stringify( student ) }])